# Interception Relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given two points $(a, b, c), (x, y, z)\in R^3$, we say that the ***midpoint*** of these two points is the point with coordinates $(\frac{a+x}2 , \frac{b+y}2 , \frac{c+z}2)$.

Take any set ***S*** of nine points from $R^3$ with *integer* coordinates. Prove that there must be at least one pair of points in ***S*** whose midpoint also has *integer* coordinates.

Can someone help me with the prove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a binary string of length 3, say $\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 \epsilon_3$, $\epsilon_j \in \{0, 1\}$, we say that a point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with integer coordinates is *of type* $\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 \epsilon_3$ if $x_j \equiv \epsilon_j\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 2)$. For example, the point $(3,42,-16)$ is of type $100$.

Since there are only $2^3 = 8$ different types, at least two of your nine numbers must share the same type. The midpoint of these two has integer coordinates.